# Ext js with jsf

Tags: jsf, extjs

I am newbie on both jsf and extjs and currently i am working on integration of extjs to jsf .I tried to find some samples from internet but i couldn't find any. Is there any examples of it or is it possible to integrate jsf with extjs in a efficent way?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from  [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_(JavaScript_library)):

> Originally built as an add-on library
>   extension of YUI, Ext includes
>   interoperability with jQuery and
>   Prototype. As of version 1.1, Ext
>   retains no dependencies on external
>   libraries, instead making their use
>   optional.

I don't see why it there would be a problem loading the library inside a jsf page. Just load the script as you would do it in a normal html page.